# How to do something after user clicks on my EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I have an `EditText` that shows time. After user clicks the `EditText` I want to show a `TimePickerDialog`, so I set a `View.OnClickListener` to my `EditText`.

But the `OnClickListener` is behaving weirdly - I touch the `EditText` and then software keyboard appears (which I don't want). When I touch again, `OnClickListener.onClick()` is finally called and the dialog appears.

What should I do if I want the dialog to appear immediately?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Unlike most other controls, `EditText`s are focusable while the system is in 'touch mode'. The first click event focuses the control, while the second click event actually fires the `OnClickListener`. If you disable touch-mode focus with the `android:focusableInTouchMode` View attribute, the `OnClickListener` should fire as expected.

```
<EditText
        android:text="@+id/EditText01"
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

Comment: there's also android:focusable which works in both touch and non-touch mode

Comment: important here, if you want to make some additional action, like show keyboard, if you add this, keyboard is not able to type onymore :(

Comment: Thanks your answer was helpful

Answer (score 57):

Another solution is to use the `ontouchlistener`:

```
edittext.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
            mQuaternion_1.setText("" + mQ1);
        }

        return true; // return is important...
    }
});
```

If it returns `true` the event is handled and keyboard wont popup. If you'd want the keyboard to still popup and register click you'd have it return `false`.

Comment: I would choose this as correct answer for the generic question "How to do something after user clicks on my EditText". No changes on xml and keyboard status is easyly managed. Others answers turns the EditText into a Button.

Comment: Thanks! I needed this to put a `selectAll()` on my `EditText`, so I did still want the keyboard to be up. Returned false and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you don't want the user to actually be able to type in the EditText.  You just want them to be able to pick a time via a time picker.  So why not just a button that pops up a TimePickerDialog?  You could display the time that was picked in a TextView.

Or you could just replace the EditText view with a [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) view (not a dialog, just a regular view).

Comment: I want to use EditText only because it looks much nicer in my app than a button. I know I could achieve the same effect by using a button with appropriate drawables but just using edittext is simpler (I don't have to create the drawables etc.)

Comment: Just a note... you wouldn't have to really create any drawables, just tell the button to use the EditText's drawables.

Comment: In this case, try android:editable="false" on your EditText view.  You should still be able to capture onClick events, but since it's not editable the soft keyboard shouldn't pop up.

Comment: Using Button with custom drawable and a few xml attributes was very simple after all, thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you just need something like

```
<EditText android:text="@+id/EditText01" android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true" android:inputType="none" />
```

not editable and clickable. Set the `OnClickListener` and you're done.
In theory, in the practice you should add too

```
android:editable="false"
```

which is deprecated but does the trick.

Comment: Worked for me. What's the problem ?

Comment: With your code the keyboard doesn't open but it still calls my onClick() on the second click, not on the first. I tested it on Android 2.0.1 and my app has minSdk 3.

Comment: i'm experiencing the same behavior as @fhucho mentions above.

here are the properties i've set on my EditText object:

`<EditText
android:clickable="true" 
android:editable="false"
android:inputType="none" <!-- disables the keyboard from automatically showing up when one taps inside of the EditText -->
android:textSize="18sp"
/>`

is there anyway to fire off an event on the first tap? and not the second tap? similar to iOS' `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` delegate?

thanks in advance! cole

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by using a customized Button like this:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="test"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of touch Listener use Text Change Listener:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //yourFunction();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```