# EditText needs clicking twice to open search dialog

Tags: android, search, android-edittext

My application has two EditText elements. Both implement the OnClickListener like this:

```
editText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Open search dialog
        doSomeStuff();
        }
    });
```

`doSomeStuff()` means: Clicking on the text field opens a search dialog via `onSearchRequested()`. The search result is written back to the text field.

This works fine but if I click the other text field I always have to click twice before the search dialog comes up. Where does that come from and how can I change that so that the search dialog comes up when clicking only once?

Comment: See the top answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119072/android-how-to-do-something-after-user-clicks-on-my-edittext

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119072/android-how-to-do-something-after-user-clicks-on-my-edittext/2284973#2284973

Answer (score 0):

For EditText fields it is better to use an OnKeyListener. With the passed in KeyEvent you can then react differently depending on how the EditText field got clicked/get focus.  Otherwise you can also try a OnFocusChangeListener or if you want to use TextWatcher to see each character that is added you can implement a TextWatcher and use addTextChangedListener..