# Open Spinner while touching a TextField

Tags: android

I have an EditText and a spinner and I want to open the spinner when I gets focus on the Edittext. How to do that in android.?
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach `OnFocusChange` listener to editText. when the edittext gets focus call `performClick()` method of spinner to open the spinner

### Example

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity{
    EditText tv = null;
    Button btn = null;
    Handler h;
    Spinner s;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    h = new Handler();

    s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.planets, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);
    EditText et = null;
    et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(hasFocus){
                s.performClick();
            }
        }
    });
    // Open the Spinner...


    // Spawn a thread that triggers the Spinner to open after 5 seconds...
//    new Thread(new Runnable() {
//        public void run() {
//            // DO NOT ATTEMPT TO DIRECTLY UPDATE THE UI HERE, IT WON'T WORK!
//            // YOU MUST POST THE WORK TO THE UI THREAD'S HANDLER
//            h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
//                public void run() {
//                    // Open the Spinner...
//                    s.performClick();
//                }
//            }, 5000);
//        }
//    }).start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem you have. What I did was, I used a **Button** instead of **EditText**. And *onClick* of **Button** I displayed the **Spinner**. The selected value of **Spinner** appears on the **Button** as *text*. I hope that won't be a problem. Still if you want code, let me know.
For **EditText** to be clicked see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119072/android-how-to-do-something-after-user-clicks-on-my-edittext) post.