# Android doesn't detect click on EditText

Tags: android, datepicker, textview

I am working on an Android tablet application with a little bit complex forms (layout has a ListView and the layout with the form included so I have to inflate EditText) . My idea is that if I click on a TextView where the date is shown the DataPicker would be shown in dialog.

The problem is that click is not detected. There is no Logs.

Java:

```
    public static EditText datep;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.admissions_all);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        View inf = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.admissions, null);
        datep = (EditText) inf.findViewById(R.id.date_value);

        datep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("Date", "You clicked me mate!");
                showDatePickerDialog(v);
            }
        });

    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        Log.i("Date", "I want to show datePicker");
    }

    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day= c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
             datep.setText(day + "." + month+ "." + year);
        }
    }
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/general"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/general"
        android:layout_below="@+id/general"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Data"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:background="#333333" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/date_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date_desc"
            android:ems="9"
            android:inputType="date" >
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/date_value"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/date_value"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Date:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I followed this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Comment: can you see the log inside onClick.

Comment: Is this code is written in an activity?

Comment: Why are you using **View inf**.?

Comment: i think you give your textview as wrap_content in your xml, then you click correctly to the text only it work, upload your xml

Comment: Yes, it's in an actvity. I have to inflate textview because main layout (R.layout.admissions_all) has the layout with the form included (R.layout.admissions)

Comment: i think you upload part of xml layout file

Comment: I have made a huge mistake. I want to click on EditText not TextView. I'm so sorry. I didn't uploaded whole XML file because it's huge (14 EditTexts, 16 TextView, 2 Views inside of 3 RelativeLayouts)

Comment: If you tried with setOnFocusChangeListener ?

Comment: I tried OnFocusChangeListener and OnTouchListener. Nothing happens, no logs.

Comment: why don't you use simple `Button` with UI appearance of `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set date_value's focusable in touch mode to false. You can do so either by adding `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` to your xml or in your code with `datep.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);`. This should then have your on click event fire. (tested on emulator)

See also: [How to do something after user clicks on my EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119072/android-how-to-do-something-after-user-clicks-on-my-edittext)

Reference: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/12/touch-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any `dateup.setclickable(true);`, try to add this. Maybe that's why it's not work , You can also debug it and see , if it call the `onlciklistner`  or not

I saw that you wrote something like this.

```
datep = (EditText) inf.findViewById(R.id.date_value);
```

when you have this

```
setContentView(R.layout.admissions_all);
```

It means that you `editText` is in another Activity , but you are setting his `onclickListner` in another one , so it will not work. Initialize his `onlcikListner` in the activity, that content view is inf.xml. If all these will not help please add more part of your Code

Regards Hayk Nahapetyan

Answer (score 0):

Could you change the DatePickerFragment to DatePickerDialog. Then do a DatePickerDialog.show();
Something like :

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = null;
datep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Date", "You clicked me mate!");
            showDatePickerDialog();
        }
    });

private void showDatePickerDialog() {
    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, new DateSetListener(), year, month, day);
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```