# Android onclicklistener doesn't work the first time when clicked

Tags: android

I've got a EditText with default text on it.

Now when a user clicks on that EditText the default text should be changed to something.

What I've got is:

- I click on the EditText the cursor comes after the default text nothing happens
- When I click again then the onClickListener works

How can I fix this that it is done from the first time?

This is my xml:

```
                 <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/step"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:hint="@string/hnt_message"
                    android:text="Default text"
                    android:maxLength="@integer/max_free_msg_length"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    />
```

This is my fragment code:

```
 private EditText editMessage;

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_step, container, false);
    ButterKnife.inject(this, mContentView);


    editMessage = (EditText) mContentView.findViewById(step);
    editMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clearEditMessageText();
        }
    });
}
```

I know I could use butterknife to for this button but I did and that didn't worked.

Comment: Do you want the user to enter text in your EditText? If not use TextView.

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119072/android-how-to-do-something-after-user-clicks-on-my-edittext

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Set focusable on EditText to false. First click gains focus to EditText.

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/step"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:hint="@string/hnt_message"
                    android:text="Default text"
                    android:maxLength="@integer/max_free_msg_length"
                    android:maxLines="2"
android:focusable="false"
                    />
```

UPDATE:
Ok, in your case you can do it with `onFocusChangeListener` instead of `onClickListener`.

```
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if (b) {
                    //do something
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes I know but then the users can't select it anymore after they did that. It must be possible to change the text as much as the user wants.

Comment: @user1007522 look at updated answer. I think it should work as you expected.

Comment: @user1007522 also if only want to remove default text, may be you can use hint? It will be automatically removed when user start typing.

Comment: It works thanks. No because then the user couldn't give a empty comment.

Comment: I think it will be better, to show error for user, when he tries to send empty comment and don't send smth default. Even if you want to send default in this case, you always can do it under the hood. I mean you don't need to show to user this stub comment.

Comment: @user1007522 and if it work, please mark answer as solution for other users of SO

Comment: I did :-) I never forget that. It popped up that I had to wait for 3 min.

Comment: @AlexanderMikhaylov this will fire when user leaves the fragement or activity because the focus will change, what is someone wanted to fire only when item selected...

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with an editText where I wanted the player to enter a character name. I didn't like using a hint as the hint is also put in the popup keyboard window, I wanted that initially blank. So I initially added the name request in the editText. I wanted that erased when first clicked. The first click triggered the popup keyboard, but not 'setOnClickListener' to erase the field. I solved the issue by calling a performClick action on the 'setOnFocusChangeListener'.

This still seems a bit of a hack to me, but changing focusable or focusableInTouchMode to false as has been suggested prevents the popup keyboard from showing.

```
charnameEditText.setText("Enter Name Here");
....
charnameEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                view.performClick();
            }
        }
});

//Normally not called by first click
charnameEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           charnameEditText.setText("");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file for the Layout onClick choose the appropriate function in your code.

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="460dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick_Action_Function" />
```

In your actual code do this

```
public void onClick_Action_Function(View view) {

        //do stuff
    }
```

Do not do this (this will make the first onClick function try to call the second onClick function)

```
public void onClick_Action_Function(View view) {

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this might help some people. I tried all other suggestions and nothing worked.
I implemented the addOnLayoutChangeListener and then started a CountDownTimer of 1 millisecond then in the  'onFinish' did a  (edittext).performClick();

```
 activeListView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
                                   int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            if ( bottom < oldBottom) {
                new CountDownTimer(1, 1) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        //editText.setText("Seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    }
                    public void onFinish() {
                        chatMessage.performClick();
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        }
    });
```