# onclick Edittext, popup a date input dialog fragment

Tags: android, datepicker, android-edittext, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have created an edit text to capture date. On setOnClickListener of edittext I am displaying the date doalog box. I select the date on this dialog box and the selected date gets set on the edittext.

Everything is working perfectly fine just that the **setOnClickListener event is not getting fired when I click on the edittext the first time. I need to click again on the edittext to show the dialog box.**

May be there is some property that I need to set for the edittext. 
Here is the edittext

```
<EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtDOB"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="@string/dateFormat"
                        android:inputType="date"
                        android:longClickable="false"
                        android:maxLength="10"
                        android:textAlignment="textStart"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />
```

Here is the onclicklistener event

```
dob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                java.util.Calendar today = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
                YY = today.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
                MM = today.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);
                DD = today.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                Log.e("current DD/MM/YY", DD+"/"+MM+"/"+YY);
                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                        PremiumCalculation.this,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                        mDateSetListener,
                        YY, MM, DD);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
```

Can anyone guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android onclicklistener doesn't work the first time when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680105/android-onclicklistener-doesnt-work-the-first-time-when-clicked)

Comment: Please set android:focusable="false" in EditText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this two additional attributes to your edittext xml and implement onClick event for it

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

First You have to create a class named `DatePicked` or whatever you want and write a code for DataPikcerDaialog popup.

```
public class DatePicker extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

ImageButton btnDatePicker;
EditText txtDOB;

public DatePicker(View view, EditText txtDOB){
    btnDatePicker = (ImageButton) view;
    this.txtDOB = txtDOB;
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this, year, month, day);
}
@Override
public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
    String date = day + "/" + (month+1) + "/" + year;
    txtDOB.setText(date);
}
}
```

You can use either EditText or TextView. And if you are using EditText then make sure you disable your EditText.

And in which activity you want to popup DatePickerDialog, you have to call this class like this-

```
final EditText txtDOB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDOB);   
txtDOB.setFocusable(false);      //Disable Your EditText
txtDOB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(view, txtDOB);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            datePicker.show(ft, "Date Picker");
        }
    });
```

This will open DatePickerDialog and display selected Date in your EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..
add this two things ..

```
 android:clickable="true"
 android:editable="false"

<EditText
   android:id="@+id/Birthday"
   custom:font="@string/font_avenir_book"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:editable="false"
  `enter code here` android:hint="@string/birthday"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason, it's happening because when we click on editText for the first time the cursor shift on that and editText gets focusable. try it

```
android:clickable="false"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

as

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_doc_date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:hint="Document Date*"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLength="40"
                android:digits="1234567890-/"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/black_color" />
```