# Android trouble in setting text from Edit TextView from alert dialog to EditText View

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an Text View on which when user click will open a alert dialog. The dialog consists of Edit Text and a button. In Edit text when user enters it's height and clicks on "OK" button,the entered height will gets displayed to the Edit Text.

MainActivity.java

```
et_weightAndHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_weightAndHeight);

        et_weightAndHeight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(AccountActivity.this);
                 View promptView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);


                 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AccountActivity.this);
                 alertDialog.setView(promptView);



             final EditText input =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        et_weightAndHeight.setText(input.getText().toString());



                    }
                });

                AlertDialog aD = alertDialog.create();
                aD.show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

prompts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Weight in lbs : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextDialogUserInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What's the main issue here ? If you are trying to set the values from the dialog, then just pass the edit text value to the textview to the MainActivity using extras. M assuming that you are using a custom dialog.

Comment: Can you please tell me one thing 
      
I made the Edit Text clickable for dialog box to appear but I have to click it twice in order for alert dialog to appear. What to do in this case I want to dialog in one click only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without proper explanation and logcat, I am assuming you are getting `NullPointerException` because you haven't initialized the `TextView` inside the dialog properly.

Change,

```
final TextView input =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);
```

to

```
final TextView input =(TextView)promptView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);
```

Comment: I made the Edit Text clickable for dialog box to appear but I have to click it twice in order for alert dialog to appear. What to do in this case

Comment: I want to dialog in one click only

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2284973/1564821. it will solve your `onClick` issue too.

Comment: actually it was nothing. I was testing it in emulator and when i was clicking on the edit text view i was counting it as first click where as it was not, when i checked it on phone it was running smooth .
Thanks for your guidance