# How to Show my DrawableRight image only after EditText is filled (or touched)?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, textview, android-edittext

[image]I am having a Edittext , in which user enters their 10 digit mobile number. I want that when user completes entering the 10 digits , the drawableRight should be visible. How can i do this?

The DrawableRight is initially hidden/invisible.

Also a 2nd way can be that , when the Edittext is touched the drawable right can be seen.

Please help me in this.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list1mobile"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/list1email"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/list1email"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/list1email">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingStart="24dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/avenibook"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:text="Mobile Number "
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/avenibook"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:text="+91 "
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/mobiledes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/avenirltsdoman"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:hint="Enter Mobile number"
                    android:textColorHint="#87888A"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_verifybutton"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_verifybutton"
                    android:drawablePadding="2dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to implement on click listener on edit text field in order to do something against the listener. this answer may help you have a look ata it.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119072/how-to-do-something-after-user-clicks-on-my-edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider changing the input type to Phone in edittext. Change the position of `R.drawable.your_icon` to the first argument if you want it to be at the start.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //hides the drawable
            if(editText.getText().toString().length()!=10)
                editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
            //shows the drawable
            else
                editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,R.drawable.your_icon, 0);
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: The code is working like charm. I Just changed the parameters of method setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.your_icon, 0, 0, 0)  to  (0, 0,R.drawable.your_icon, 0) ,
as drawable is needed on Right side.

Comment: Also, do not use multiple linear layouts since it takes more rendering power and causes a laggy experience for the user. Try to minimise the number of view groups you have. An alternative is to use RelativeLayout/ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use a linear layout for this because a linear layout puts all design in linear so you can't put it in drawable right.

Comment: ok i will take out the Linear layout..But how to show the drawable right after Mobile Number is  entered? Thats my question

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.